# Zipping one month old files

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a script to zip a set of files into one zip file if the number of files go above a limit.

```
    limit=1000                        #limit the number of files

files=( /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/*.pcap)     #file format to be zipped  

if((${#files[0]}>limit )); then   #if number of files above limit
zip -j /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/capture_zip-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").zip /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/*.pcap 

fi
```

I need to modify this, so that the script checks for number of files from previous month rather than the whole set of files. How do I implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete update:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Limit of your choice
LIMIT=1000
#Get the number of files, that has `*.txt` in its name, with last modified time 30 days ago
NUMBER=$(find /yourdirectory -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +30 | wc -l)
if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]
then
  FILES=$(find /yourdirectory -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +30)
  zip archive.zip $FILES
fi
```

The reason I am getting the files twice, is because the bash array is delimeted by space, rather than `\n`, and I couldn't find a clear way to count the number of files, you might want to do some research on that to make find once.

Comment: @jishnuUNair I will have a look at that. Your requirements are, look for the files that are older than 1 month, if the number of those files exceed LIMIT, zip them, is that right?

Comment: @jishnuunair please have a try on the updated answer, and feel free to ask me if any questions!

Comment: @JishnuUNair Maybe we have different versions of zip, it works for me on rhel 6.1. Seriously, I guess the point here is, to get an idea how to do something, not to get the answer doing something. :)

Comment: yes , i got the method, its working in my virtual machine, but when i try it in this main system, it shows this too long argument. Anyways, im working on a workaround that problem :)

Comment: Simple Solution : increase stack size :)

Comment: @jishnuunair well done, you mean by changing the OS stack size?

Comment: @jishnuunair if my answer helped you and you like it, please kindly select it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This script perhaps.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || {
    echo "You need Bash to run this script."
    exit 1
}

shopt -s extglob || {
    echo "Unable to enable extglob option."
    exit 1
}

LIMIT=1000
FILES=(/mnt/md0/capture/dcn/*.pcap)
ONE_MONTH_BEFORE=0
ONE_MONTH_OLD_FILES=()

read ONE_MONTH_BEFORE < <(date -d 'TODAY - 1 month' '+%s') && [[ $ONE_MONTH_BEFORE == +([[:digit:]]) && ONE_MONTH_BEFORE -gt 0 ]] || {
    echo "Unable to get timestamp one month before current day."
    exit 1
}

for F in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    read TIMESTAMP < <(date -r "$F" '+%s') && [[ $TIMESTAMP == +([[:digit:]]) && TIMESTAMP -le ONE_MONTH_BEFORE ]] && ONE_MONTH_OLD_FILES+=("$F")
done

if [[ ${#ONE_MONTH_OLD_FILES[@]} -gt LIMIT ]]; then
    # echo "Zipping ${FILES[*]}."  ## Just an example message you can create.
    zip -j "/mnt/md0/capture/dcn/capture_zip-$(date '+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S').zip" "${ONE_MONTH_OLD_FILES[@]}"
fi
```

Make sure you save in unix file format and run `bash script.sh`.

You could also modify the script to get files by arguments instead by:

```
FILES=("$@")
```

Comment: Brilliant! but shouldn't this `-gt LIMIT` be this `-lt LIMIT`? What does the `<   <` construct do?

Comment: @konsolebox  thanx for the reply, but can you please explain what you have done cause, the script is not working the way I want it.Thanks :)

Comment: @JishnuUNair What errors messages do you see and what changes did you apply to it?

Comment: @konsolebox the script doesnt zip any files, the changes i made where only on the path of the files to be zipped.

Comment: @JishnuUNair Yes but what can you post the error messages? Make sure your path expands to expected pattern. Do `echo <place-your-path-expression-here>` and you should see the expected files.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `if` line with

```
if [[ "$(find $(dirname "$files") -maxdepth 1 -wholename "$files" -mtime -30 | wc -l)" -gt "$limit" ]]; then
```

From left to right this expression

- searches (`find`)
- in the path of your pattern (`$(dirname "$files")` strips away everything from the last "/")
- but not in its subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`)
- for files matching your pattern (`-wholename "$files"`)
- that are newer than 30 days (`-mtime -30`)
- and counts the number of those files (`wc -l`)

I prefer `-gt` for comparisons, but else it is the same as in your example.

Note that this will only work when all your files are in the same directory!